# Find parametric equations that produce reasonable facsimiles of these surfaces

Tags: calculus, parametric

> The accompanying ﬁgure shows the graphs of two parametric
>   representations of the cone $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ for $0\leq z\leq2.$
>   [image: figure]
>   
> $(a)$ Find parametric equations that produce reasonable
>   facsimiles of these surfaces.

For ${\rm I}$, I notice that in $xy-$plane it's just circle which vary for $z$. Using is fact, $$x=r\cos\theta,\quad x=r\sin\theta,\quad z=r^2 \text{ where } 0\leq r\leq \sqrt 2,0\leq \theta\leq 2\pi$$ But how to solve for ${\rm II}$. **Please answer it as I can also figure it out for general surfaces also**.
Thanks in advance and thanks for your time .

Comment: Are you sure your third equation should be $z=z$? // For II, it looks like the isoparametric curves are along $x$ and $y$ respectively.

Comment: You are right. It's a typo.